# Session Timeout when you are idle and before signing out triggering a JavaScript fancybox saying you are about to sign out, using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, dynamic, timeout

I am working on a rails app wherein I need to implement a functionality that if the user is idle for certain time(say 10 minutes), a fancy/light box pops up saying that you are about to sign out.Do you want to "logout" or "keep me logged in".

I tried implementing it by expiring the session cookies(using 'expire after'  option). So it's signing out if the user is idle for a certain time but I need to popup a window(that I already have in the form of view). The problem is I don't know when I have to trigger it. I don't know when the idle time starts and it's going to sign out after the specified time. The code is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**jQuery idleTimer Plugin**](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/). I think this is what you are looking for. I have used it in my application but the difference is, in my case i don't need fancy pop-up in my requirement. For that fancy pop-up you have to research in that plugin your self

Comment: seems unsupported and not maintained to stable version .